# What's that filter called?

Tags: javascript, opengl, glsl

What is the name of a Filter which filters in a 4x4 region. Adding up all values of the pixels , then dividing it by 16.
Is this a gaussian filter?

Pseudo Code

```
    for (int i = -2; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = -2; j < 2; ++j) {
            result += Texture2D(texture,ij).rgb;
        }
    }              
    result *= 0.0625 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a box filter - here is a link to an explanation etc

http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/boxfiltering/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about the [Mean filter, or average filter](http://www.librow.com/articles/article-5):

> The basic idea behind filter is for any element of the signal (image) take an average across its neighborhood.